# Can i do 3d swivel animations along the z-axis with HTML5 / js?

Tags: javascript, windows-mobile, html

http://gizmodo.com/5523721/microsoft-office-on-windows-phone-7-looks-fantastic

I was wondering if it was possible to obtain an effect similar to the windows 7 mobile examples above without using Flash. I would like to have content swivel in along the z-axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. But Windows Mobile got very poor support for modern web technologies, so it will be hard, if not impossible to do it on Internet Explorer on Windows Mobile.

In order to do 3D like graphics and animations you can use CSS3 3D transforms (iPhone Webkit and nightly Snow-Leopard Macs only) or SVG.

Comment: The OP is referring to the default transition effect on Windows Phone 7 (currently in pre-release), and whether it would be possible in HTML 5 on a supporting browser.

Comment: It is possible using the experimental CSS3 3D Transforms or using SVG.

Comment: I'd put that in your answer :)